# How to use entity-framework to migrate to a new named database with whole data

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I used entity framework 6 to migrate the database, and the name of the database was not the same before and after. I first used the template to create a library.
The link string is

```
<add name="TODO_WebAPIContext" connectionString="Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=TODO_WebAPIContext-20190308135710; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|TODO_WebAPIContext-20190308135710.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

This library comes with a dbo.todolist table with some data
Later I want to migrate this database to this connection string with fully data and structure

```
<add name="TODO_WebAPIContext" connectionString="Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=TODO_WebAPI; User ID=sa;Password=sqlserver2008"providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I execute successively
1,enable-migrations and set to true
2. The add - migration test
3, update the database
Then I moved to the new library, but the TodoList table does not have the previous data. Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move everything to a new database, i believe you will have to delete the previously created migrations folder . Execute the Enable-Migrations on new database, add-migrations and update-database. Cheers !

Comment: Thanks so much
I did what you told me. 
I first created a library called TODO_WebAPIContext, which contains a TodoList table that contains some data, that is, not an empty table.
Then I used a new initial-catalog to migrate to a new library named TODO_WebAPI. 
I used enable-migrations, add-on Migration Initial, and update-database successively. The Migrations folder was deleted before adding, but when i completed this, I found the TODO_WebAPI.dbo.TodoList was an empty table
Can you help me again?

Comment: Hey IChuan, i've just tested on a project that i have and performed the following steps with success , i dropped the MigrationHistory  table beforehand, enabled migrations , added new migrations , verified the migration file and it got populated with all the create scripts and updated database with success. Hopefully it works for you as well  !

Comment: Thanks so much,i will try it again,hope you have a nice day^_^

Answer (score 0):

Mostly I did like this if i need move to new server and database.
Its very simple , just change your connection string database name.
exp. SampleDB1 to SampleDB2.
And you must going to project folder.Click url box , tpye cmd.

run this command , dotnet ef update database , dotnet ef initial migrations , and update 
 your context like dotnet ef update mycontext.